# How to POST base64 to Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, base64, webmethod

I want POST one parameter which is `base64` to `webservice`, but it doesn't work.

```
    string postData = "base64=hySGNg22yX0AIjNQvNJw0xHEbi32NH+iRVKDkbOmUiKpxW0/S6rUgfLmSa527Y8zZ3GmEzfXMB8ry8fH5GjGeJFGqFxDC4A2hLlvIFzyiDeUCqloGDAJoOLa8Jnif1C8nwRte0GNCRM5RXkshLKZP2itZclgDCYz6OgAF7oLNluoB44cZ3AgF1Q8hVgME8LeqgOqxsIzTt3Xn+96j7zp/wA=";
    byte[] dataArray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(ServerPage);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    Stream dataStream = null;
    try
    {
        dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    dataStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
```

but parameter in `requestHeader` changes to:

`base64=hySGNg22yX0AIjNQvNJw0xHEbi32NH%2BiRVKDkbOmUiKpxW0%2FS6rUgfLmSa527Y8zZ3GmEzfXMB8ry8fH5GjGeJFGqFxDC4A2hLlvIFzyiDeUCqloGDAJoOLa8Jnif1C8nwRte0GNCRM5RXkshLKZP2itZclgDCYz6OgAF7oLNluoB44cZ3AgF1Q8hVgME8LeqgOqxsIzTt3Xn%2B96j7zp%2FwA%3D`

so WebService receives a wrong parameter:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GenerateOrder(string base64)
{ 
    byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64); //Exception here
}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure of the answer, hence the comment but can't you try to encode the String before and after you send it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(base64)`, before converting it back from `base64`.

Comment: i changed the code to string b = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(xmlStr);
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(b); but still not working... return The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.  but if i remove byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(b); thie line .. it worked...

Comment: What is xmlStr? I do not find that in your example code. If I take the requestHeader value from your example, and decode it, I get exactly the value from 'postData'.

Comment: Does your string contain the 'base64=' part? You might have to remove that first, before converting it from base64.

Comment: I solved it, byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        string Base64StrData = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer).Replace("+", "%2B"); Just add this..Cause the plus sign after passing through the Url into spaces so get illegal Base64 string,now it worked.. 
        string postData = "str=" + Base64StrData;